# SQL outer join one table with 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some SQL help. I am a Java guy by trade and I really don't know even how to ask this question.  I have 3 tables,  Call them  Person, Children, Friends.  Person is an ID and a Name:

```
|   id   |    name    |
---------------------
|    1   |    Joe     |
```

Let say Children is the same but with a FK back to person

```
|   id   |    personId    |   name   |
-------------------------------------
|   1    |       1        |   Frank  |
|   2    |       1        |   Dan    |
```

and friends are the same thing

```
|   id   |    personId    |   name   |
-------------------------------------
|   1    |       1        |   Will   |
|   2    |       1        |   Bob    |
```

Obviously this is a simplified version of my real problem, but the structure is the same.  I need to pull all of this data in one SQL pull such that I get this back

```
 | personId  | personName  |  childId  | childName |  friendId  |  friendName
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |     1     |    Joe      |     1     |   Frank   |   null     |    null
 |     1     |    Joe      |     1     |   Dan     |   null     |    null
 |     1     |    Joe      |    null   |   null    |     1      |    Will
 |     1     |    Joe      |    null   |   null    |     2      |    Bob
```

I have tried multiple join techniques, but can’t seem to crack it.  SQL was never my best subject.  Now I am parsing this into a Java object person with List<>  of friends and children so obviously this will work too:

```
 | personId  | personName  |  childId  | childName |  friendId  |  friendName
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |     1     |    Joe      |    null   |   null    |   null     |    null
 |   null    |    null     |     1     |   Frank   |   null     |    null
 |   null    |    null     |     1     |   Dan     |   null     |    null
 |   null    |    null     |    null   |   null    |     1      |    Will
 |   null    |    null     |    null   |   null    |     2      |    Bob
```

Anything that will allow a clean for loop in my code to build this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert but two full outer joins on person.id = children.personId and person.id = friends.personId should work.  What have you tried and what results were you getting?

Comment: @mreff555 this is tagged MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
     p.id    as personId
  ,  p.name  as personName
  ,  c.id    as childId
  ,  c.name  as childName
  ,  null    as friendId
  ,  null    as friendName
from person p
  inner join child c
    on p.id = c.personId
union all 
select 
     p.id    as personId
  ,  p.name  as personName
  ,  null    as childId
  ,  null    as childName
  ,  f.id    as friendId
  ,  f.name  as friendName
from person p
  inner join friend f
    on p.id = f.personId;
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/BSPEC33394

returns:

```
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| personId | personName | childId | childName | friendId | friendName |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
|        1 | joe        | 1       | frank     | NULL     | NULL       |
|        1 | joe        | 2       | dan       | NULL     | NULL       |
|        1 | joe        | NULL    | NULL      | 1        | will       |
|        1 | joe        | NULL    | NULL      | 2        | bob        |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure inner join would return nulls? I think you should use left outer join instead

Comment: @bksi click the rextester link and see check it out.  http://rextester.com/BSPEC33394

Answer (score 1):

You could outer join with the union of children and friends, and then check which of both you are matching with to determine what to output in each column (using `case when`):

```
select    person.id,
          person.name,
          case when rel.kind = 1 then rel.id   end as childId,
          case when rel.kind = 1 then rel.name end as childName,
          case when rel.kind = 2 then rel.id   end as friendId,
          case when rel.kind = 2 then rel.name end as friendName
from      person
left join (
           select id, personId, name, 1 as kind
           from   children
           union all
           select id, personId, name, 2 as kind
           from   friends
          ) as rel
       on rel.personId = person.id
order by  person.id,
          rel.kind
          rel.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN to acheive this:

```
SELECT 
     p.id    as personId
  ,  p.name  as personName
  ,  c.id    as childId
  ,  c.name  as childName
  ,  f.id    as friendId
  ,  f.name    as friendName  
FROM person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN child c ON p.id = c.personId
LEFT OUTER JOIN friend f ON p.id = f.personId;
```

More info for left joins you can read here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp